# Why does this completion of a Sobolev space contain constant functions? Please explain text.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Below, $\mathcal{C} = \Omega \times (0,\infty)$, $x$ refers to the variable in $\Omega$ and $y$ to the variable in $(0,\infty)$, and $\Omega$ is a bounded smooth domain. $tr_\Omega:H^1(C) \to L^2(\Omega)$ refers to the trace operator $tr_\Omega u = u(\cdot,0)$. [image]

How do I know that the constant functions are in that bigger space (let's just take $\epsilon =1$)? They obviously have finite $H^\epsilon(\mathcal{C})$ norm but surely that is not enough?

---

**Old version of the question**:
Let $X$ be a Hilbert space with norm $|\cdot|_X$. Define $Y$ as the completion of $X$ under a function (norm?) $|\cdot|_Y$, which satisfies $|x|_Y \leq C|x|_X$ when $x \in X$.

I guess then $y \in Y$ means that there exist $x_n \in X$ such that $(x_n)$ converges to $y$ in the $Y$ norm.

Is it possible to say that if $|y|_Y < \infty$, then $y \in Y$? That is, if $y$ has a finite norm (think of $Y$ as some Sobolev space and $y$ here as some function) then is it in $Y$?

---

Comment: If $x_n$ is Cauchy with respect to $|\cdot|_X$ then $|x_n-x_m|_X<\epsilon/C$ for $n,m$ large. This implies that $|x_n-x_m|_Y<\epsilon$ for $n,m$ large. Therefore, if a sequence is Cauchy with respect to $|\cdot|_X$ it is Cauchy with respect to $|\cdot|_Y$. That is what gives you the inclusion.

Comment: @Pp.. I understand the inclusion, my question is different.

Comment: It is hard to give an answer to your question, without any background. For instance, what is $C$ and how is defined $H^1(C)$. What is $tr_\Omega u$? What is $\nabla_x$ or $u_y$?

Comment: @Tomás I added it. $H^1(C)$ was not defined in the work http://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.7406v3.pdf.

Comment: Well, you gave the answer to your question in the last line and that's it.

Comment: @Tomás $H^\epsilon$ is defined as a completion. I don't see why "$v \in H^\epsilon$ iff the RHS of (2.16) [in the pasted image] is finite". For the standard Sobolev spaces, such two versions of spaces are proved to be equivalent.

Comment: Well, if that's the problem then, you can easily overcome it. Define a Lipschitz function $F$ in the following wayt: $F_n(x,y)=1$ if $x\in \Omega $ and $y\in (0,n)$; $F_n(x,y)$ linear if $x\in\Omega$ and $y\in [n,2n]$ and $f(x,y)=0$ for $x\in \Omega$ and $y>2n$. If $g(x,y)=c$ ($c\in\mathbb{R}$), for all $x,y$, consider the sequence $G_n(x,y)=F_n(x,y)g(x,y)$. The sequence $G_n$ belongs to $H^1$ and it does converge to $c$ in $H^\epsilon$ when $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @Tomás I did think that. However, I am not sure it converges in $H^\epsilon$, specificially (just take $c=1$), we need $\lVert (F_n)_y \rVert_{L^2(\mathcal{C})}^2 = \int_n^{2n}\int_\Omega k^2 \to 0$ where $k$ is the coefficient of the linear part. Is it obvious that this tends to zero? I'm not sure it does since the gradient stays the same..

Comment: No, instead of $[n,n+1]$, consider the interval $[n,2n]$. Then, the coefficient will be $1/n$, thus $$\int_{n}^{2n} 1/n^2=n/n^2=1/n$$

Comment: Ahh I understand. I originally had $(n, n+1)$, and forgot that the coefficient changes when interval is changed to $(n, 2n)$.Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your question is well posed. When you say "if $|y|_Y < \infty $" then it seems you are implicitly assuming that $y$ is an element of $Y$.
Indeed if $y$ were not an element of $Y$, then the expression $|y|_Y < \infty $ would not be defined.

Comment: Please see my edited post you will know what I mean.